# How Remove Odd Hidden Web Field in My Form

Tags: forms, code-injection, hidden-field, square, javascript-injection

I'm redoing some stuff on a website.  I create my own forms and there's been a hidden field injected into my system somehow, after my **Submit** button.  I have (updated) found that it is injected by `Square` payment processor (95% confidence).  But it does not show up on my published site, only my workstation.

`<input name="nds-pmd" type="hidden" value="{&quot;jvqtrgQngn&quot;:{&quot;oq&quot;:&quot;1440:1595:1440:1706:1440:2560&quot;,&quot;wfi&quot;:&quot;flap-138151&quot;,&quot;oc&quot;:&quot;q400qo6n8n86q525&quot;,&quot;fe&quot;:&quot;1440k2560 24&quot;,&quot;qvqgm&quot;:&quot;300&quot;,&quot;jxe&quot;:135975,&quot;syi&quot;:&quot;snyfr&quot;,&quot;si&quot;:&quot;si,btt,zc4,jroz&quot;,&quot;sn&quot;:&quot;sn,zcrt,btt,jni&quot;,&quot;us&quot;:&quot;q7008390np2s6777&quot;,&quot;cy&quot;:&quot;ZnpVagry&quot;,&quot;sg&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;zgc\&quot;:0,\&quot;gf\&quot;:snyfr,\&quot;gr\&quot;:snyfr}&quot;,&quot;sp&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;gp\&quot;:gehr,\&quot;ap\&quot;:gehr}&quot;,&quot;sf&quot;:&quot;gehr&quot;,&quot;jt&quot;:&quot;78r9qs3735260548&quot;,&quot;sz&quot;:&quot;54p61p7n7s97rn3&quot;,&quot;vce&quot;:&quot;apvc,0,5r54nr06,2,1;fg,0,,0,,0,,0,,6,,0;zz,11583,1p9,121,f_nq_cebsvyr_pbhagel;gf,0,11583;zzf,3r9,0,n,231 163,798 27,34n,34n,-28rp,2787,-568;zzf,3r7,3r7,n,45 0,122q 0,221,220,-16n0,9s60,snq;zzf,3r8,3r8,n,0 9r,7058 201,1666,164o,-3r062,22786,-10nn;zzf,3r8,3r8,n,45 27,2063 2n0n,q13,q00,-opp0,r62n,355q;zz,rq,429,278,;zzf,2sp,3r8,n,2sp 1nr,p3qo 3170,2484,2490,-55s3n,5q156,-2rnr;zzf,3rp,3rp,n,ABC;zzf,3r5,3r6,n,ABC;zzf,3r9,3r9,n,ABC;zzf,3r9,3r9,n,ABC;zzf,3r8,3r8,n,ABC;zzf,2717,2717,32,ABC;gf,0,163nr;zzf,270r,270r,32,ABC;zzf,2713,2713,32,ABC;gf,0,1o1ps;zzf,2711,2711,32,ABC;zzf,2711,2711,32,ABC;gf,0,1sss1;zzf,270s,270s,32,ABC;zzf,rn67,rn67,1r,ABC;gf,0,31167;zzf,rn67,rn66,1r,ABC;gf,0,3sopr;zzf,rn60,rn61,1r,ABC;gf,0,4r62r;zzf,rn64,rn64,1r,ABC;gf,0,5q092;zzf,rn62,rn62,1r,ABC;gf,0,6ons4;zz,o93o,540,2n0,;gf,0,7742s;zz,oq54,500,1o,pbyyncfvoyrAnione;gf,0,83183;xx,s78,0,f_nq_cebsvyr_anzr;ss,3,f_nq_cebsvyr_anzr;zz,960,24q,1n6,;so,2s2,f_nq_cebsvyr_anzr;zz,2914,57p,2o5,;gf,0,87664;xx,48q,0,f_nq_cebsvyr_anzr;ss,0,f_nq_cebsvyr_anzr;so,147,f_nq_cebsvyr_anzr;xx,4,0,f_nq_cebsvyr_pbzcnal;ss,0,f_nq_cebsvyr_pbzcnal;zp,15,150,os,f_nq_cebsvyr_pbzcnal;zp,4s,150,os,f_nq_cebsvyr_pbzcnal;so,qpo,f_nq_cebsvyr_pbzcnal;zz,12,234,1r1,;xx,1q76,0,f_nq_cebsvyr_pbzcnal;ss,3,f_nq_cebsvyr_pbzcnal;zz,np,26r,17o,f_nq_cebsvyr_hey;so,1os,f_nq_cebsvyr_pbzcnal;xx,3,0,f_nq_cebsvyr_hey;ss,1,f_nq_cebsvyr_hey;zp,8n,270,17o,f_nq_cebsvyr_hey;so,qqs,f_nq_cebsvyr_hey;gf,0,8o8pr;zz,396o,522,140,;xx,315,0,f_nq_cebsvyr_hey;gf,0,8s54r;ss,0,f_nq_cebsvyr_hey;so,n55,f_nq_cebsvyr_hey;&quot;,&quot;ns&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;jg&quot;:&quot;1.j-952168.1.2.fVkluNjuPtiX7Vz4XSTgDD,,.mAaD01S5Ua73V84EfsG1-uOIddNorAK-95Azs1LvMa0uvVIaED2hQNisAwd1fTk6qFNCd4_spoDT2y2hGdBtS-J4nYKw_tRoHws_-BjCJvskfveCoDIdUiA8gKgtHY_8ssdVnS4P2YZ_tTqtFWLKudkmBMwTEhnDl3-2Eingfx7fmrVZwPPbvb6yYPMsOLJD2kTSqr78jmmpmh2iOoNem9GwMmJ1YGtybtCKAcG2KNxCDgLzd0b0OHQsA1Fki15J&quot;}">`

I'm using `Chrome`. This now (updated) looks like some `Square` injection.  I'm finding it on Safari and Firefox as well, same values inside the field.  Again, it is not showing up on my production served site.

Comment: Hey Rich, could you confirm if this field shows up when using incognito mode with all extensions disabled?

Comment: Same thing happens...even on a different box.

Answer (score 0):

Update.

No `JavaScript` injection.  The payment processor was responsible, and I had never seen this before.

Comment: I'm getting the field too.  Is it something to do with the sandbox?  I think it's reasonable to assume that Square might want to play with (undocumented, separate) form fields for various purposes and to leave them alone.

Comment: It was Square.  It was odd that it took that long for them to validate it was them.

Comment: I have the same issue, and even in production. It's causing problems with my URLs.

Comment: @Edward Contact Square, tell them about this thread.  Get on Slack and talk to them.  They can help chase it up for you.